# Given a connected graph with edges >= vertices, find an algorithm in O(n + m) that orients the edges such that every vertex has indegree of at least 1

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem. I was thinking we would need to detect a vertex in a cycle, then run DFS on it while also orienting the edges along each vertex u in the cycle, to be directed from u to some vertex v incident to it. But I am not sure what edges cases I might be overlooking, or whether the idea is sufficient. Below is one such example.

[image: One such example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.** Find *any* spanning tree $T$ for the graph $G=(V,E)$. Number of its edges is $|V|-1$.

**Step 2.** Find *any* edge $\{u,v\} \in E$, which *doesn't* belong to the tree $T$. It can be done because $|E| \ge |V|$.

**Step 3.** Choose the vertex $v$ as "root" for the tree $T$ and orient all the edges in the tree $T$ "from" this root.

**Step 4.** Orient the edge $\{u,v\}$ from the vertex $u$ to the vertex $v$. Arbitrarily orient all the remaining edges, which aren't oriented yet.

Answer (score 2):

Start with any vertex $v_s$, and do a BFS from that $v_s$ to discover the entire graph.  When you traverse an edge, you orient it away from the start node.

Now every vertex $v \in V \setminus \{v_s\}$ has $\deg_{\text{in}}(v) > 0$.

Find a path from $v_s$ to any vertex $v_t$ such that $\deg_{\text{in}}(v_t) \geq 2$.  Since the input graph is not a tree, such a vertex must exist.

Flip all edges in the path.

This graph satisfies your requirement since

1. every *internal* vertex $v_i$ in the path still has $\deg_{\text{in}}(v_i) > 0$,
2. $v_t$ now has $\deg_{\text{in}}(v_t) \geq 1$ (it decreased by one), and
3. $v_s$ has $\deg_{\text{in}}(v_s) > 0$.

Running time: $O(n + m)$.